# How to obtain the real-time properties of a custom title bar in C++/WinRT WinUI3

Tags: winui-3, c++-winrt

1. What I get from m_mainWindow.MyBut().ActualOffset() or m_mainWindow.MyBut().TransformToVisual() is 0. The value of the coordinate attribute will only change when the window changes.
2. I tried the link that has properties that may provide coordinates https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.button?view=winrt-22621
3. How do I get the coordinates of this element? I saw an example in C# that can get the coordinates like this. I don’t know if it’s a problem with C++/WinRT WinUI.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "TitlebarPage.xaml.h"
#if __has_include("TitlebarPage.g.cpp")
#include "TitlebarPage.g.cpp"
#endif

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Controls;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Navigation;
using namespace Microsoft::UI::Input;


namespace winrt::SampleApp::implementation
{

    winrt::hstring defaultTitle = L"WinUI C++ Desktop sample App";

    TitlebarPage::TitlebarPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        TitlebarCustomBtn().PointerPressed({this, 
        &TitlebarPage::TitlebarCustomBtn_Click});
        TitlebarCustomBtn().PointerPressed({ this, 
        &TitlebarPage::TitlebarCustomBtn_Click });
    }
  
    void TitlebarPage::OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs const& e)
    {
            m_mainWindow = e.Parameter().as<MainWindow>();
            
            AppWindow appWindow = m_mainWindow.MyAppWindow();
            m_appWindow = appWindow;
            m_changedToken = m_appWindow.Changed({ this, 
            &TitlebarPage::AppWindowChangedHandler });          
    }

    void TitlebarPage::AppWindowChangedHandler(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable 
    const& sender, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Windowing::AppWindowChangedEventArgs const& e)
    {
        if (e.DidSizeChange() 
         && sender.as<AppWindow>().TitleBar().ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar())
        {
            SetCustomTitleBarDragRegion();
        }
    }

    void TitlebarPage::TitlebarBrandingBtn_Click(
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable const& /*sender*/, 
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& /*e*/)
    {
        m_appWindow.TitleBar().ResetToDefault();
        m_mainWindow.MyTitleBar().
        Visibility(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed);

        m_brandTitleBar = !m_brandTitleBar;
   
        if (AppWindowTitleBar::IsCustomizationSupported() && m_brandTitleBar)
        {
            m_appWindow.Title(L"Default titlebar with custom color customization");
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ForegroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().BackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().InactiveBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().InactiveForegroundColor(Colors::Transparent());

            //Buttons
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonForegroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().
            ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().
            ButtonInactiveForegroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonHoverBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonHoverForegroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonPressedBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonPressedForegroundColor(Colors::Transparent());   
        }
        else
        {
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ResetToDefault();
            m_appWindow.Title(defaultTitle);
        }
    }

    void TitlebarPage::TitlebarCustomBtn_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable 
     const& /*sender*/, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& /*e*/)
    {

        if (AppWindowTitleBar::IsCustomizationSupported() && !m_customTitleBar) {
            m_customTitleBar = true;
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar(true);

            // Show the custom titlebar
            m_mainWindow.MyTitleBar().
            Visibility(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Visible);

            // Set Button colors to match the custom titlebar
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonForegroundColor(Colors::Gray());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().
            ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonInactiveForegroundColor(Colors::Gray());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonHoverBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonHoverForegroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonPressedBackgroundColor(Colors::Transparent());
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ButtonPressedForegroundColor(Colors::Gray());               
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().
            IconShowOptions(IconShowOptions::HideIconAndSystemMenu);
            //Set the drag region for the custom titlebar
            SetCustomTitleBarDragRegion();
        }
        else
        {
            // Bring back the default titlebar
            m_customTitleBar = false;
        m_mainWindow.MyTitleBar().
        Visibility(winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed);
            m_appWindow.TitleBar().ResetToDefault();
        }
    }

    void TitlebarPage::ResetTitlebarBtn_Click(winrt::Windows::Foundation::IInspectable 
    const& /*sender*/, winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs const& /*e*/)
    {       
    m_mainWindow.MyTitleBar().Visibility(
    winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Visibility::Collapsed);
        m_appWindow.TitleBar().ResetToDefault();
        m_appWindow.Title(defaultTitle);
    }

    void TitlebarPage::SetCustomTitleBarDragRegion()
    {

        double scaleAdjustment = 
        m_mainWindow.MyTitleBar().XamlRoot().RasterizationScale();
        double scaleAdjustment2 =m_mainWindow.MyBut().XamlRoot().RasterizationScale();

        GeneralTransform transform = m_mainWindow.MyBut().TransformToVisual(nullptr);
        
        static Rect bunds;
         bunds = transform.TransformBounds(Rect(0, 0, 
                                                m_mainWindow.MyBut().ActualWidth(), 
                                                m_mainWindow.MyBut().ActualHeight()));

        std::vector<Windows::Graphics::RectInt32> dragRects;
        Windows::Graphics::RectInt32 MyButRect;

        MyButRect.X = static_cast<int>(bunds.X * scaleAdjustment);
        MyButRect.Y = static_cast<int>(bunds.Y * scaleAdjustment);
        MyButRect.Height = static_cast<int>(bunds.Height * scaleAdjustment);
        MyButRect.Width = static_cast<int>(bunds.Width * scaleAdjustment);
        dragRects.push_back(MyButRect);

        InputNonClientPointerSource nonClientInputSrc = 
        InputNonClientPointerSource::GetForWindowId(m_appWindow.Id());
        nonClientInputSrc.SetRegionRects(NonClientRegionKind::Passthrough, dragRects);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please tell us why you want to get the coordinates of this element? What do you want to realize? If you want to get the coordinates of the element, you could try to use the `VisualTreeHelper` go down from the `title bar` to the `UIElement`and then you could get the postation of the UIElement.

Comment: I want to implement a custom animation effect in the status bar. When the mouse focuses on the title bar, the elements in the title bar will be displayed and animated. When the mouse loses focus and leaves the title bar, the elements will be hidden. As far as I know we can't operate the close and zoom buttons

Comment: The caption controls (system Close, Minimize, and Maximize buttons) are still available and handled by the system.

If you want to operate the close, Minimize, and Maximize buttons, as far as I'm concerned, there is no way.

For another UIElement, you need to creat a full title bar customization and then you could control the appearance and hiding of UIElement when the mouse focus or leaves. You could refer to the Doc: [Title bar customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/develop/title-bar)